# How can i change the Farm Admin account in the SharePoint 2016

Tags: 2016, central-administration, sharepoint-search, farm-admin, sharepoint-administration

I have installed and configured SharePoint using the *"OLDFARMACCOUNT"*.
Unfortunately, i've created all the services including search services using that *"OLDFARMACCOUNT"*. Later i got to know that there is a SharePoint rule, **"You shouldn't use same account for FARM and SERVICES".**

For this, I've created *"NEWFARMACCOUNT"* and add it to the Managed Account in the Central Administration. And changed the Farm Account to the *"NEWFARMACCOUNT"* under the *"Configure Service Accounts"* in the Central Admin.

After this change, i faced problem with the *"Search Services"*, it shows login issue for the *"NEWFARMADMINACCOUNT"*.
Now i reset these changes.

Can anyone please let me know, is it okay to change the *"FARMACCOUNT"* after the installation?
 
If YES, Please share the exact steps to change the *"FARMACCOUNT"*.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below :-

Log into the Central Administration -> Security -> General Security -> Manage service accounts.

You will see a screen like this 
[image]

Use the **Drop down to select appropriate service applications** and change the account for them from list of options present under the "**Select an account for this component**".